# Protractor: I need to wait until the component shows in the screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I've got a problem, I need to wait until the component shows in the screen, sometimes the components delays too long to show up. I need to wait until some field, or variable becomes true. Someone knows how to do this?

```
element(by.id('nextStage-button')).isPresent().then(function (visible) {
    let i = 0;
    while (visible !== true){
        browser.sleep(2000);
        console.log("test "+ i++);
        if(visible === true){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using [Expected Conditions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions).

You could do something like this:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const nextStageButton = $('#nextStage-button');
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(nextStageButton), 3000);
// do whatever you wanted to do once it's visible
```

Answer (score 1):

**browser.wait()** will schedules a command to wait for a condition to hold or promise to be resolved.

This function blocks WebDriver's control flow, not the javascript runtime. It will only delay future webdriver commands from being executed (e.g. it will cause Protractor to wait before sending future commands to the selenium server), and only when the webdriver control flow is enabled.

**Documentation link**: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait

In your case you want to wait until a specific element is visible and for this you should use **isDisplayed()** as it will return a promise that will be resolved with whether this element is currently visible on the page.

```
await browser.wait(async () => await el.isDisplayed(), DefaultTimeout);
```